# open guide inside GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, python-sphinx

I wrote a GUI in Python and wrote the documentation using Sphinx.

I would like to try and put an help button that opens the HTML file with the guide.

Any help?

Comment: This depends highly on the GUI toolkit you're using, of course.  Some have a built-in HTML display ability that you could use.  Others don't, so the best you could do is open the HTML file in the user's default browser (using the `webbrowser` module, probably).

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution that worked for me:
I first added a menu option in the GUI (created with QT designer)

```
self.actionHelp.triggered.connect(self.handle_help_menu)
```

then as the GUI initializes:

```
os.chdir('docs')
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output('make html',shell=True)
subprocess.check_output('make latex',shell=True)
```

the function connected to the menu that opens the html that contains the guide is:

```
def handle_help_menu(self):
    import webbrowser
    url='file://' + os.path.realpath('./docs/build/html/index.html')
    webbrowser.get(using='google-chrome').open(url,new=2);
```